# Can two boost lockfree queues cause deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, queue, lock-free

My overall design is to have multiple producer threads (>2) to generate results into two

```
   atomic<bool> processing_done=false; // when all producers finished
   // will set to true
   boost::lockfree::queue<ObjA, capacity<100>> Q1;
   boost::lockfree::queue<ObjB, capacity<100>> Q2;

   ==== code segment in a single writer thread ====
   while (!processing_done) {
      if (Q1.pop(bap)) {
          singleWrite.write(bap);
      }
      if (Q2.pop(pairbap)) {
          singleWriter.write(pairbap);
       }   
   }
```

Both queues are lockfree so there should not be any deadloack issues. However, my program run happily for a while processing almost 1/2 of the large input. Then the above loop stopped writing results to the output file. The producer saw that the queue is full and could not push to the queues any more.

Of course, my program is much more complicated than the above.  Not sure my problem is coming from using two queues.  Anyone has any experience in such situations.

After commenting out one queue my problem still persists. So must be some other places cause the deal lock.

Comment: It would help to know what `processing_done` is, what `write` does, and what kind of synchronization is used in `write`. It's possible that calls to `write` are happening simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

Even with locking, the containers don't share the locking mechanism, so no they will never deadlock.

However, do remember that several successive atomic operations are not atomic as a whole, which is a much bigger problem and likely the cause of your issue.